# Extracting Specific File from Disk Image

Tags: data-extraction, dd, computer-forensics

Supposing that we have a disk image with E01 or DD format etc. Is there any command to extracting specific file like system32.dll only from it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to extract individual files from the image. You could e.g. mount the image, parse the MFT$ and then copy the sectors out of the file via dd. Alternatively you can use a Windows based tool, [FTK Imager](https://accessdata.com/product-download/ftk-imager-version-4-5) (free of charge)